# MySQL query returning duplicate result

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My mysql query is returning duplicate issue. I dont know why. I want someone to please look in to it and advice.

I have two table xyz1 and xyz2

xyz1 contain employee data while xyz2 contain employ health check.

The thing I want to achieve is, I want to count number of health checks for a male employ.

```
select COUNT(*) as Num 
  FROM xyz1 
    INNER JOIN xyz2 
          ON xyz1.cid = xyz2.cid 
 WHERE xyz1.gender = 'male'
```

It is returning duplicate error.

Please help

Comment: when you say duplicate error. what do you mean? 2x the expected results or an actual error?

Comment: Is it `cid` the employee code?

Comment: "I want to count number of health checks for a male employ"? *A* male employee? Which one? You don't have any criteria to query on a particular employee. Or do you want the *avarage* number of health checks of male employees? Or what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to find the number of health checks performed for male employees you'd want

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_HEALTH_CHECKS_FOR_MALES
  FROM XYZ1
  INNER JOIN XYZ2
    ON XYZ2.CID = XYZ1.CID
  WHERE XYZ1.GENDER = 'male'
```

which is what you've already got.

If you're trying to determine the number of male employees who have had at least one health check the query would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_MALES_WITH_HEALTH_CHECKS
  FROM XYZ1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CID
                FROM XYZ2) t2
    ON t2.CID = XYZ1.CID
  WHERE XYZ1.GENDER = 'male'
```

And it you want to find out how many health checks each male employee has had you'd want to use

```
SELECT XYZ1.CID, COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_HEALTH_CHECKS
  FROM XYZ1
  INNER JOIN XYZ2
    ON XYZ2.CID = XYZ1.CID
  WHERE XYZ1.GENDER = 'male'
  GROUP BY XYZ1.CID
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was looking for second type of query. 
First query was returning 6 results. 4 from xyz1, 2 from xyz2.
but I was just looking for 4 results from xyz1